# Can I get mouse events in a QGraphicsItem?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qmouseevent

I have subclassed `QGraphicsRectItem`, and it's not receiving any mouse events. I've seen other questions similar to this say I need to enable mouse tracking, but `setMouseTracking` is in QWidget, and QGraphicsItem does not appear to be a QWidget.

I've implemented `paint`, and that's working. In my subclassed QGraphicsView I am getting mouse events.

The docs seem to think I should just override the mousePressEvent function (for example) and I should start getting the events. Whether I forward the mousePressEvent to the superclass of my QGraphicsView or not doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your subclassed QGraphicsView, you need to call the default implementations of overridden mouse event methods if you want them to propagate down to the items. For example:

```
CustomView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    // handle the event as you like

    QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event); // then call default implementation
}
```

If you want to accept hover events, you need to call `QGraphicsItem::setAcceptHoverEvents(true);`. Otherwise you do not need to enable any particular mouse tracking.

EDIT: Here is a full working example:

```
#include <QtGui>

class CustomView : public QGraphicsView
{
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        qDebug() << "Custom view clicked.";
        QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
    }
};

class CustomItem : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
    {
        qDebug() << "Custom item clicked.";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    CustomItem item;
    item.setRect(20, 20, 60, 60);

    QGraphicsScene scene(0, 0, 100, 100);
    scene.addItem(&item);

    CustomView view;
    view.setScene(&scene);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I tried that, as stated in the question. I have a breakpoint on the mousepress event in the QGraphicsItem, and it is not called regardless of whether or not I do `QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);`

Comment: @Almo Are you overriding any mouse events in a subclassed QGraphicsScene?

Comment: In my QGraphicsView subclass, I create a QGraphicsScene, and call setScene with it. I have not subclassed QGraphicsScene.

Comment: @Almo See edits for a working example. My guess is that your `QGraphicsItem::boundingRect()` isn't returning the right rect, or if you've reimplemented `QGraphicsItem::shape()`, it isn't right.

Comment: Ok, I'll check this. I have implemented boundingRect, but maybe that's been done wrong.

Comment: Argh. `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent`. I was looking for `QMouseEvent` as an argument, because the `QGraphicsView` overrides use those. I hadn't noticed they were different for the `QGraphicsItem`. Your example pointed that out. I'm embarassed. :)

Comment: @Anthony, I implemented a QGView class trying to make it work (even tough I didn't really needed it), however I already implemented a QGScene class... I figured out I only had to add `mouse...Event()` to my inherited QGS class, so I wanted to add (that I assume that) it won't work if you add the `mouse...Event` method to both the view and the scene classes, it should be one or the other. In my case the view caught it and didn't pass it to the inherited QGRectItem, but I solved it now. Thank you all!

Answer (score 8):

I went through the same problems you have encountered and I wanted to add some insights on top of Anthony's really good answer. Here is an example I wrote showing some features that can be implemented using the mouse events and the keyboard events.

Note that the events do not propagate to `QGraphicsItem`s in a `QGraphicsItemGroup` or in a `QList<QGraphicsItem>` (it took me a while to figure that out).

```cpp
#include <QtGui>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>

class CustomItem : public QGraphicsEllipseItem
{
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
    {
        if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            if(event->modifiers() == Qt::ShiftModifier) {
                qDebug() << "Custom item left clicked with shift key.";
                // add the item to the selection
                setSelected(true);
            } else if(event->modifiers() == Qt::AltModifier){
                qDebug() << "Custom item left clicked with alt key.";
                // resize the item
                double radius = boundingRect().width() / 2.0;
                _center = QPointF(boundingRect().topLeft().x() + pos().x() + radius, boundingRect().topLeft().y() + pos().y() + radius);
                QPointF pos = event->scenePos();
                qDebug() << boundingRect() << radius << this->pos() << pos << event->pos();
                double dist = sqrt(pow(_center.x()-pos.x(), 2) + pow(_center.y()-pos.y(), 2));
                if(dist / radius > 0.8) {
                    qDebug() << dist << radius << dist / radius;
                    _isResizing = true;
                } else {
                    _isResizing = false;
                }
            } else {
                qDebug() << "Custom item left clicked.";
                QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);
                event->accept();
            }
        } else if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
            qDebug() << "Custom item right clicked.";
            event->ignore();
        }
    }
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
    {
        if(event->modifiers() == Qt::AltModifier && _isResizing){
            QPointF pos = event->scenePos();
            double dist = sqrt(pow(_center.x()-pos.x(), 2) + pow(_center.y()-pos.y(), 2));
            setRect(_center.x()-this->pos().x()-dist, _center.y()-this->pos().y()-dist, dist*2, dist*2);
        } else if(event->modifiers() != Qt::AltModifier) {
            qDebug() << "Custom item moved.";
            QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
            qDebug()<<"moved"<<pos();
        }
    }
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
    {
        if(event->modifiers() == Qt::AltModifier && _isResizing) {
            _isResizing = false;
        } else if(event->modifiers() != Qt::ShiftModifier) {
            QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
        }
    }

    int type() const
    {
        // Enable the use of qgraphicsitem_cast with this item.
        return UserType+1;
    }
private:
    QPointF _center;
    bool _isResizing;
};

class CustomScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
    {
        qDebug() << "Custom scene clicked.";
        QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event);
        if(!event->isAccepted()) {
            if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
                // add a custom item to the scene
                QPointF pt = event->scenePos();
                CustomItem * item = new CustomItem();
                item->setRect(pt.x()-25, pt.y()-25, 50, 50);
                item->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable|
                              QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
                addItem(item);
            } else if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton) {
                // check whether there is an item under the cursor
                QGraphicsItem * itemToRemove = NULL;
                foreach(auto item, items(event->scenePos())) {
                    if(item->type() == QGraphicsItem::UserType+1) {
                        itemToRemove = item;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(itemToRemove) {
                    // remove the item from the graphicsScene
                    removeItem(itemToRemove);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
    {
        qDebug() << "Custom scene moved.";
        QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    }
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event) {
        if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Backspace) {
            // remove all selected items
            qDebug() << "selected items" << selectedItems().size();
            while(!selectedItems().isEmpty()) {
                removeItem(selectedItems().front());
            }
        } else {
            QGraphicsScene::keyPressEvent(event);
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    CustomItem item;
    item.setRect(20, 20, 60, 60);
    item.setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable|
                  QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);

    CustomScene scene;
    scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    scene.addItem(&item);

    QGraphicsView view;
    view.setScene(&scene);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Hope it helps too!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with a view not accepting mouse clicks.  The problem was that I needed to enable the view ( ui->view->setEnabled(true)  ).