# QT mousePressEvent isn't triggered

Tags: c++, qt

im making a flappy bird game using QT however it doesn't seem like my mousePressEvent is triggered when i click my mouse.
here is my code :

```
void flappybird::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button()==Qt::RightButton )
    {
        setPos(x(),y()-20);
        setTransformOriginPoint(50,50);
        setRotation(-20);
    }
}
```

Comment: What class does flappybird inherit?

Comment: it inherits QGraphicsPixmapItem and QObject

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get mouse events in a QGraphicsItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591635/can-i-get-mouse-events-in-a-qgraphicsitem)

Comment: Change `void flappybird::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)`  to `void flappybird::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)`

Comment: still nothing :/

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve]